# ReSharper: Show datatips of intellisense list items when mouse over

Tags: resharper

Using R# IntelliSense, when I move mouse over items in the list, only background color of items changed to emphasize the item under mouse. But, I want to see datatip of the item under mouse.

**Note:** At below images, mouse pointer is over `LogMethodCall` item.

**Happened:**

[image]

**Desired:**

[image]

**Edit:**
This behaviour was formerly available (may be in a previous version of ReSharper) and so useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pressing the `CTRL + Space` (Symbol code completion) keyboard shortcut then try using the `CTRL + ALT + Space` (Smart code completion) shortcut to get the current method to be highlighted. (Note, these shortcuts are for the Visual Studio scheme, they will be `CTRL + Space` and `CTRL + SHIFT + Space` respectively for the IDEA scheme)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these shortcuts did what i wanted. What i wanted is to highlight method (or prop/field/abbr.) which is **under the mouse**. This behaviour was formerly available, may be in a previous version of the ReSharper.